# What is the motivation of this inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

> > **Problem**
> >     Let
> >     $$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^2}} -1\right)$$
> >     Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_n = 1/4$.
> >
> > **Solution**
> >     We first observe that for all $x \geq -1 $,
> >     $$\frac{x}{2+x} \leq \sqrt{1+x} -1 \leq \frac{x}{2}$$
> >     Then setting $x = k/n^2$. and then... bla bla bla...

I know that the right side of the above inequality is obtained by Bernoulli's inequality, but I don't know the left side.

What is the motivation of the left side of the inequality? Does it come just by intuition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have
$$
\sqrt{1+x}-1=\frac{(\sqrt{1+x}-1)(\sqrt{1+x}+1}{\sqrt{1+x}+1}
=\frac x{\sqrt{1+x}+1}.
$$
When $x\geq0$, $1+x\geq\sqrt{1+x}$, so
$$
\frac x{\sqrt{1+x}+1}\geq\frac x{1+x+1}=\frac x{2+x}.
$$
When $-1\leq x<0$, the inequality is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Find the minimum i.e. $x=-1$ to show there equal at that point.  then take derivatives of both sides to get $2/(x+2)^2$ and $ 1/2 (x+1)^{.5} $ it's then obvious that the square root term grows much faster and has the same starting value.  This proves the inequality.